# Mac Scripting Move files on USB stick

Tags: macos, scripting

I'm completely new to mac scripting, having only done a little with VBS before, any pointers would be great. I have a USB stick with a thousand files on, what I want a script to do is pick the first letter of the file name and move to a folder of that same letter name, then within that folder I want to pick the second letter of the file name and move to that folder. I want it to loop through the entire folder structure moving the files.

Example ATest.txt would be moved to Folder A\T.

Comment: Moving files off the USB stick onto your internal drive? Or not? Differentiating between upper and lower case - so you will have sub-folders `a` and `A`? Or not? Creating all possible folders including ones without content? Or not?

Comment: Files are still on usb stick, not differentiating between sub folders, creating folders including ones with out content.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, let's say your USB stick is called "USB Stick", if not, replace later as appropriate.

First and foremost - make a backup of the stick and preferably your whole Mac if you use TimeMachine.

Start Terminal by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> and starting to type *"Terminal"*. When it guesses correctly, hit <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd>. That is a *"Spotlight search"* and is the quickest way to find files and programs on a Mac, btw.

Now change directory to be on your USB stick, using the `cd` command. Note that **macOS** always mounts external drives under `/Volumes`:

```
cd /Volumes/"USB Stick"
```

Create a useless file:

```
touch "Freddy Frog"
```

Now use Finder to look on your USB stick and be sure you are in the same place - stop here if you don't see `Freddy Frog` in Finder.

Now create the directories:

```
mkdir -p {a..z}/{a..z}
```

Use `{A..Z}/{A..Z}` if you want your directories in upper case instead.

Now save the following `bash` script as "MOVER" in your HOME directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nocaseglob nullglob

# Loop through all files beginning with two letters followed by anything else
for f in [A-Z][A-Z]*; do 
   let0=${f:0:1}                 # Extract first letter
   let1=${f:1:1}                 # Extract second leter
   newdir="$let0/$let1"          # Build name of new directory
   echo Moving $f to $newdir/$f
done
```

Then, in Terminal, while still in the `/Volumes/"USB Stick"` directory, you can run the script. It won't change anything on your computer, but it will tell you what it would do and you can check it looks correct:

```
bash $HOME/MOVER
```

Once you have tried and tested that, you will need to make sure you have made a backup, then replace the penultimate line in the script, i.e. the one that starts with `echo`, with this one and run it again:

```
mv "$f" "$newdir"
```